# Parse complicated XMLs in weird format using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have received weirdly formatted xmls in the format below:

```
<File xml:space="preserve">
     <Subfile keyword="Store" tag="0">
          <Value number="1">Amazon</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Owner" tag="1">
          <Value number="1">Alice Murphy</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Date" tag="2">
          <Value number="1">20161114</Value>
     </Subfile>
</File>
```

In this case, what would be the most efficient way to retrieve the value "Alice Murphy" without having to parse the entire XML?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve the value without parsing the xml file. What "Caleb Haldane" has posted is a easy way to achieve your goal, though it will parse the file internally. So either you are looking for a way so you dont have to parse it yourslef (in which case the answer is given by "Caleb Haldane"). Otherwise there is no way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Why do you call this "weirdly formatted"?  It looks like normal XML to me.

Comment: @n247s Thanks.  That makes sense.

Comment: @ajb Because the original files all have around 50 attributes for each Subfile element, which I thought was weird.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the node you want with xpath.

The xpath below Looks for Value nodes of Subfile Nodes, where the keyword is "Owner"

```
// parse the XML as a W3C Document
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("<xml path and filename>"));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/File/Subfile[@keyword='Owner']/Value";
Node ownerNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Comment: Thanks. One clarification though.  The line with "Owner" is giving me error messages.   But the error disappears when I deleted the "/" after "Value".  Is that the correct path format?

Comment: @ruby_le You are right I transferred the xpath statement from another site and forgot to trim it.

Comment: The quotes around `"Owner"` need to be escaped for Java's benefit. I've edited them to single quotes.